# Can Selenium be used in a stand-alone c# program?

Tags: c#, selenium, bots

is it possible to integrate the Selenium tests into an own program in C# and the user only has to execute the program which then performs actions in the browser without the user having installed Selenium?

My goal is to create a bot that performs certain actions on a website that the user has previously configured in a WinForm/WPF program.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion that should generally be possible, but it might be tricky.
For the Microsoft Internet Explorer there is a driver needed. If you want to use Chrome you will have to use the open source implementation and a driver.
These drivers are only executables, which could be deployed with the *.exe


If you want to use Firefox the user needs to install the Version cooperating with the Selenium version.
You can look up the supported Versions for Firefox and Co [on the selenium page](https://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp).

I hope i could help you a bit...

Comment: Yes thanks, but how can I use Selenium Test without Visual Studio? I Just created a test which open Browser etc. works well in Visual Studio with Nunit and Selenium Package, but how can I compile this and run this without the Studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured "stuff" and test steps in windows forms, just create a "RUN" button that will execute the test. Well, at this point, whatever your test does, should no longer be a "test", it should be a function that takes whatever input you have from your form, and do steps accordingly.

For example:

```
public void RunTest()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //Or whatever driver you use.
    /*
    *   Do all your "test" steps.
    *   
    *   Basically, in here put all code from SetupTest & Test Method & Teardown 
    *   methods so the browser is initialized, all steps are done, and the browser
    *   is closed in the end.
    */
}
```

And just call RunTest() when your button is pressed. Of course, at this point like I said, this is not a test, it's just a function that opens the browser and (with the help of selenium), does whatever you want it to do.